# Multiple \the... formats for a single counter?

Tags: counters, labels

Say I have a definition (`\arabic`) that includes a small list of sub-definitions (`\alph`).
Sometimes I want to use full cross-references (**2.3a**, **2.3b**, ...). But sometimes, when the main definition is clear from context, I want to use short cross-references (**a**, **b**, ..).

But I can only define one `\thesubdefinition` macro. So my question is: is there a recommended way to tie more than one formatting to a single counter (i.e., one `\label`)? In the 'user code' I imagine using `\ref` for the full reference and `\shortref` for the short one:

```
\newcounter{subdefinition}[definition]
\def\subdef#1{\refstepcounter{subdefinition}(\alph{subdefinition}) #1}
```

...

```
\begin{definition} \label{def}
    Bla bla technical stuff:
    \subdef{simple axiom}\label{simple}, 
    \subdef{complex axiom}\label{complex}.
    Note that axiom~\shortref{complex} is more complex than axiom~\shortref{simple}.
\end{definition}

We will focus mostly on axiom~\shortref{complex}).  % axiom b
```

...

```
Recall that axiom~\ref{complex} is very complex.  % axiom 2.3b
```

I could probably hack something, but maybe there's a package for this?

Comment: I'd say to look at the `zref` package.

Comment: There's also the cleveref package and its \creflabelformat command. One might imagine two different ways to format the label.

Comment: @Bernard: The `cleveref` package cannot tinker with the internals of the label (i.e., the `\thecounter` macro). All it allows you to do is surround it with parentheses and such. It would have been handy if `cleveref` had the solution, since I'm already using it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[user]{zref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newcounter{subdefinition}[definition]

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{subdef}{}
\zref@newprop{fulldef}{}
\zref@addprop{main}{subdef}
\zref@addprop{main}{fulldef}

\newcommand\subdef[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subdefinition}%
  \zref@setcurrent{subdef}{\alph{subdefinition}}%
  \zref@setcurrent{fulldef}{\thedefinition\alph{subdefinition}}%
  (\alph{subdefinition})~#1%
}
\newcommand{\shortref}[1]{\zref[subdef]{#1}}
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\zref[fulldef]{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A definition}

\begin{definition} \label{def}
Bla bla technical stuff:
\subdef{simple axiom}\zlabel{simple}, 
\subdef{complex axiom}\zlabel{complex}.
Note that axiom~\shortref{complex} is more complex than axiom~\shortref{simple}.
\end{definition}

\section{A reference}

We will focus mostly on axiom~\fullref{complex}.

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to use `\zlabel` for setting a label for `\subdef`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A perfectly valid answer to my question. It's just a shame that a whole set of new commands is required to make this work. In particular, it means that I can't use `cleveref` anymore, which I left out of the original question for simplicity's sake. :-) Anyway, if I have to use a different `\label` command on the document level anyway, I might as well use two counters in the background, which is what I've now done.